# Client error handling for custom stripe checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to catch Stripe errors that customer sees after entering invalid card data. I'm using Stripe checkout.js in the same way like in another StackOverflow question: [Error handling for custom stripe checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895295/error-handling-for-custom-stripe-checkout)

And according to the @Ywain answer there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43896401/5008606)

> Checkout validates the card information with the issuing bank. If the information is invalid, then the error is displayed directly to the customer in the popup form

What can I do to be aware of such errors (in order to log them)? Can I disable frontend errors and catch all errors in the backend? Or is there some way to catch such errors in a javascript handler? Thanks!

Comment: You can't log these types of errors, it's just not possible with how Checkout is designed. If you need more fine-grained control over the exact authorisation and charge attempts, you could use Elements.

Comment: @karllekko got it, thanks